# PJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pjax

My pjax doesn't work, as I see time changes..

Can you find something wrong with my code.

```
<html><head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a[data-pjax]').pjax()
</script>
</head><body>
<?php
$header = "this is first part
<br/> <a href='pjax2.php' data-pjax='main'>GO</a>";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$footer = "this is second part";
$headers = getallheaders();
if(($headers['X-PJAX'] == 'true')){
echo "<div id='main'>first change</div>";
}else{
echo "$header<br/>$date<br /><div id='main'>first page</div><br />$footer";
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Best,
MJ

Comment: I think you need to put your `.pjax()` function inside a `$(document).ready(function(){});` .

Comment: Precisely what does this have to do with Ruby On Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: **The main problem is that you are trying to use a cutting-edge browser feature without having mastered basic debugging of a web-page.**

You resolved the error with `getallheaders()` in php, so this should be easy for you.

Step 1: Load http://www.bluereservations.com/pjax.php, open the browser console, refresh the page and check for messages in the console.

It reports an error that `$ is not defined`. That suggests `jquery` didn't load successfully.

Step 2: Load http://www.bluereservations.com/jquery.js

One mystery solved.

AFTER getting all the obvious problems with the page out of the way, then look at more obscure things. For pjax that will involve inspection of network resources, http request and response headers, etc.

If you are using Firebug for Firefox then read http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel for details. 
For pjax you will need to turn on the `persist` option in case pjax fails.

**The following might address the other issues with your test-pages...**

When responding to a `X-PJAX` request you only send the main content, not the whole page. For your test-case something like

```
<?php $headers = getallheaders();
      if($headers['X-PJAX'] == 'true'): ?>
first change
<?php else: ?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $('a[data-pjax]').pjax(); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  $header = "this is first part
    <br/> <a href='pjax2.php' data-pjax='main'>GO</a>";
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $footer = "this is second part";
  echo "$header<br/>$date<br /><div id='main'>first page</div><br />$footer";
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

jquery-pjax does allow you to send the whole file in response to `X-PJAX` requests. Look in the docs for the `fragment` option.

Personally [HTMLDecor](http://github.com/shogun70/HTMLDecor) is a much easier way to get free `pushState` support, but I'm biased.

Comment: It still doesnt work

`<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').pjax('#main').live('click', function(){
$(this).showLoader()
});
})
</script>
<?php
$header = "this is menu part";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$footer = "this is second part";
$headers = getallheaders();
if($headers['X-PJAX'] == 'true'): ?>
<div id="main">change one<br /></div>
<?php else: ?>
<html>
<?php echo "$header $date"; ?><br /><div id="main">page one</div>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: `<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').pjax('#main').live('click', function(){
$(this).showLoader()
});
})
</script>
<?php
$header = "this is first part
<br/> <a href='pjax2.php' data-pjax='main'>GO</a>";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$footer = "this is second part";
if($_SERVER['X-PJAX'] == 'true'): ?>
<div id="main">change one<br /></div>
<?php else: ?>
<html>
<?php echo "$header $date"; ?><br /><div id="main">page one</div>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: in which part? I changed the header request because i got some errors with your option..

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide the complete source code. This is just for the purposes of making clear pjax's requirements. It's impossible to tell if this works without access to the actual test-pages.

Comment: I used your code, but changed getallheaders with `($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"])`, because i get an error otherwise..

http://www.bluereservations.com/pjax.php

Comment: I got rid of the problems with errors by changing head elements to this: `<head>
  <script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/pages.js"></script>
  <script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $('a').pjax('#main'); });
</script>
</head>`.

But it still doesn't work.. Can you tell me how to inspect network resources, http requests, response headers?

Comment: I updated the answer. Be aware that the `pages.js` script (which you have recently included) *disables* pjax.

Comment: OK, after removing pages.js this thing now works on latest version of chrome and firefox, while on ipad's safari it loads up whole pages (pjax demo site works fine loading pjax content only)..

How can I enable it for safari too?

Comment: Good job. I don't have an ipad so can't help on that issue - do a google or stackoverflow search for "ipad pushstate". By the way, if you ask a question on stackoverflow and someone correctly answers it then you should accept it. The site doesn't work otherwise. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: The problem is with the code.. It looks like safari has some issues with diving php elements, so it has to be all together..

For anyone having the same problem, better code is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733160/faux-template-issue/10733407#10733407