# Faux template issue

Tags: php

I have a problem with dividing site parts to different files so it's easier to edit, but I am having some problems.. the site doesn't work..

This is the original part which works:

```
<?php if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"]): ?>
<div id="main">first change</div>
<?php else: ?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $('a').pjax('#main');
$('#main').bind('pjax:start', function(){$('#main').animate({ height: 'hide', opacity:                    'hide' }, 'fast')})
.bind('pjax:end', function(){$('#main').animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' },   'slow')}); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$header = "this is first part
<br/> <a href='test2.php' data-pjax='main'>GO</a>";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$footer = "this is first part";
echo "$header<br/>$date<br /><div id='main'>first page</div><br />$footer";
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is what I have now, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php $body = "<div id='main'>first page</div><br /><a href='pjax2.php' data-pjax='main'>GO BACK</a>"; ?>

<?php if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"]): ?>
<?php echo "$body";?>
<?php else: ?><?php include "header.php";?>
<?php echo "$body"; ?><?php include "footer.php" ;>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Header.php is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $('a').pjax('#main');
$('#main').bind('pjax:start', function(){$('#main').animate({ height: 'hide', opacity:     'hide' }, 'fast')})
.bind('pjax:end', function(){$('#main').animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' },     'slow')}); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Footer.php is this:

```
</body></html>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" - please be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your code by : 
- Remove unused php's tags
- Be sure that `header.php` and `footer.php` are in the same directory that your current file.

```
<?php 
$body = "<div id='main'>first page</div><br /><a href='pjax2.php' data-pjax='main'>GO BACK</a>"; 

if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"]) {
    echo $body;
} else {
    include("header.php");
    echo $body; 
    include("footer.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: It works! However the code works properly only if you put all body content into "main" div, which wasn't necessary before, probably because of endif argument..